# How to get multiple list values in one single call in RedisTemplate of Jedis Client

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using RedisTemplate to get and store data as a list.
When I am storing data - I store it as

```
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("key1", "value11");
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("key1", "value12");
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("key2", "value21");
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("key2", "value22");
```

Now I want to get the list values for both the keys in one single call
I can get individually by

```
redisTemplate.opsForList().range("key1", 0, -1);
redisTemplate.opsForList().range("key2", 0, -1);
```

But is there a way to use multi get with list. If the values are of type string, I am able to use multisite, but I dont see any api with list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a dedicated API, but simply [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining).

See some examples at:
https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/PipeliningTest.java

Comment: Would be nice to have the code in the answer with how to use pipelining with RedisTemplate.

Comment: This repo is not longer available!