# How to fetch list of values from Single key in Redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have inserted one `ArrayList` into a Redis database using Java.

```
hashList.leftPushAll("myKey", fetchedCatalogs);
```

Here, `myKey` is the key and `fetchedCatalogs` is a `ArrayList` which contain some data.

Now I want to fetch this list in Java but I am not able to do it.
Please help.

Comment: Tutorial suggests `List<String> list = jedis.lrange("myKey", 0, 5);`, what do you mean by "I am not able to do it" ?

Comment: I have already tried what you have suggested but using this I can fetch only maximum 5 records. what if I have n numbers of records. How to implement that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple list values in one single call in RedisTemplate of Jedis Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898215/how-to-get-multiple-list-values-in-one-single-call-in-redistemplate-of-jedis-cli)

Comment: Instead of 5 use -1 for the penultimate member. Read the docs about https://redis.io/commands/lrange. Note that if you're always reading/writing the entire array a List is less than ideal - just serialize the entire thing and store it as a string